# Using urllib2 to download text to be used to evaluate a variable

Tags: python, urllib2

Am downloading a text page, c.txt, from a webserver.  c.txt only contains the letter 'c' .  Able to download file fine and print its contents, the character 'c'.  Cannot, however, use its contents in the code below:

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://localhost/c.txt')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
result = str(response.read())
print(result) # prints 'c' just fine
furl = "c"
furl = str(furl)
if result == furl: # Does not work
     print('Correct')
```

No errors are incurred. Just will not work

Comment: Are you sure they're the same length? Your response may have whitespace characters in it that you don't see when printing `result`.

Comment: use `print('>%s<' % result)` to see if you don't have extra spaces or "\n" as @Soviut suggest. And then use `result = result.strip()` to remove them.

Comment: I've decided to turn this into a complete answer since this seems to be the only possible explanation for the issue.

Comment: @hahobson don't forget to choose an answer if it solves your question.

Comment: result = result.strip()  Works!  Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most likely an extra white space character in the `result`. You can check for it by printing characters on either side.

```
print '>%s<' % result
```

If the result looks like `>c <` you've got a trailing white space (including newline characters).

To remove the leading and trailing white space from a string, you can use the [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) method on the string.

```
result = str(response.read()).strip()
```

Or you can do it right at the point of comparison.

```
if result.strip() == furl:
    print 'correct'
```

Comment: if result.strip() == furl:   Works !  Thank you !

Comment: @hahobson Great! What was the result you got from `print '>%s<' % result`?

Comment: @ Soviut It prints to screen, but it does not evaluate the if statement.  The text document must add some unseen characters

Comment: @hahobson what does it print though? `>c<` or `>c  <` etc.

Comment: >c
<
Is what occured.  It was a next line character.  Sorry, was just trying to finish up.  Though I am glad you persisted.